# How to resolve conflict in merge request in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I've got a merge request in gitlab:

[image: Gitlab Screenshot]

I have approved this request -- it looks good.  I want to merge with master.

When I go to "Resolve Conflicts" I get the following:

[image: Gitlab Merge Conflict Screenshot]

Note, specifically, in the default commit message, it appears to be trying to merge 'master' into '156'.   This is the opposite of what I want -- I want to merge these things into master.

Even if I solider forward and do the merge by picking one (and I'm not sure which is right because it's not clear what is 'mine' vs 'ours'... I'm returned back to the gitlab merge request page and told there are still conflicts - but now now button to do it in gitlab, only locally:

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?  Is there no method to merge via gitlab - do I have to do the merge locally and then push it?

Answer (score 6):

Gitlab is right. What you're doing here by resolving conflicts, is merging `master` in `156`.

First step before merging `156` in `master` is to have a clean tree state between the two branches, which means that all changes made on `master` should be reflected in `156` first. So yeah, you need to merge `master` in `156` before merging `156` in `master`.

## Solution

This way of resolving conflicts forces you to have that annoying commit message. What I'd suggest here is **rebasing** `156` on master, which is something you cannot achieve on Gitlab GUI. Note that this would potentially override `156`'s history with `master`'s, but that's what you need anyway.

```bash
# on branch 156
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push -f origin 156
```

---

*Note* : when rebasing `156` on `master`, `ours` would be `master` and `theirs` would be `156`.

Comment: In the original merge request -> resolve conflicts ... is 156 'ours' or is it 'theirs'?

Comment: It is just written in the answer :)